# Laravel Controller: Override parent request validation

Tags: laravel, validation, controller, request

I have a structure that has base controller called `BaseController` that all controllers extend it, and it has implementation of `index()` to view resources, base controller use default Request validation and I need to override this in a child.

When I run the below code I receive the following error:

```
Declaration of ...PostController::index(...PostRequest $request) should be compatible with ...BaseController::index(...Request $request)
```

Parent:

```
/* BaseController.php */

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

abstract class BaseController extends Controller
{    

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // logic
    }

}
```

Child:

```
/* PostController.php */

namespace App\Http\Controllers\App;

use Illuminate\Http\PostRequest;

class PostController extends BaseController
{    

    public function index(PostRequest $request)
    {
        // logic
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems you copied wrong child class

Comment: These are OOP fundamentals: you have redeclared a method with different parameters. How can Php know which one you need? You could define the parameter of the index function with an interface that both `Request` and `PostRequest` would implement. But that would create so much overhead and a virtual rewrite of the Laravel Request class, that it's just not useful. Aren't you using a too complex solution for the job? Keep it simple!

Comment: Why do you want to extend the controller like so?

Comment: @mrhn contains methods that I need to use